# ipage: Dreamweaver preview works, but not when live; thoughts?

Tags: html, safari, dreamweaver, image-uploading

So I'm simply starting up a new site, and want to get my .jpg image (literally one) called "coming_soon" up on my live site. However, when I upload to ipage, the image does not seem to render on the site. It just shows a question mark as default. I've tried with Safari and Firefox but to no avail. Here is the code below.

`<body>
<img src="images/coming_soon.jpg" width="1200" height="800" alt="coming_ssoon" />
</body>`

And CSS..

```
@charset "UTF-8"
// CSS Document 

#wrapper{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

body{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Is there something I am missing perhaps?? Any help would be great! Thanks.

-MR

Comment: keep in mind that my HTML code was auto-formatted by DW prior to any custom code involved!

Answer (score 2):

The question mark means that image doesn't exist in the correct directory. Check your spelling.

You shouldn't use Dreamweaver for preview purposes. It can't regognize your javascripts correcly and will not update when you make minor changes.